# How to change cursor

Tags: jquery, css, mouse-cursor

I have started to explore jQuery and have a question regarding how things look. I have an image that when clicked toggles the navigation bar. When I hover over the image I have the text-select cursor.

How can I change this so it looks the same as when I hover over a `href` (what looks like a hand pointer)?

Comment: why would you use jQuery is this exact case? CSS is good enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CSS you can do:

```
img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand; /* If you want to support IE < 6. See http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/cursor.html#note */
}
```

Or:

```
img{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think that if you're teaching OP to support IE5, you're actually doing a DISservice.

Comment: It's not teaching to support IE5, it's creating awareness that not every solution is cross browser. In this case it's IE5 in others it's IE7/IE8.

Comment: Great, now we're all aware, I am so filled with awareness and technology! Gotta get back to work now sorry, I've been trying all week to make `margin: auto` work in IE5 on my Myspace blog

Answer (score 2):

As others said

```
img {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

But if you want to use your 'own' hand, you can set a custom image as cursor:

```
img {
    cursor:url(img/hand-url.cur), default;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with jquery there.

you can use css there

```
.img:hover{
    cursor: auto

}
```

**[All possible cursor styles](http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/css/css_cursor_control.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have different names for the pointer :) Cross-Browser:

```
img {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

Comment: IE 5.0 and 5.5 are still browsers, aren't they?

Comment: Too bad things get downvoted even if they are as complete as possible for cross browser functionality ;-))

Comment: If someone is using IE5 in 2013 he's going to face bigger problems than a missing hand cursor

Comment: Still.. SO is for learning purposes. Cross Browser solutions, even if they are dated back to 1990, are still valuable information for someone learning

Comment: NO, THIS IS STUPID. Then why do you advise for IE5 on this and not in ANY OTHER QUESTION on Stack overflow? You can go test 90% of the accepted solutions for any html question and they won't work in IE5, still no one bothers to give a solution for that.

Comment: I'm not here to argue or discus with you about the fact if IE5 solutions are needed on SO or not. SO is a question-answer based platform, giving peole the awareness that not everything is cross-browser at first is an important thing. Why would you even care for IE8 if there are newer versions available? It's about teaching and creating awareness in situations. It's stupid to think that creating awareness for CrossBrowser solutions is not part of any CSS/HTML/jQuery solution on SO.

Comment: Right :-) this ain't worth the discussion. No one's offended you, you'd better work on your behaviour. That's the only thing childish in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have given it an id then use this:

```
$("#id").css("cursor","pointer")
```

Comment: Dear downvoter can you plz tell me one thing if someone asks you about learning cooking, would you teach or give the address to McDonalds? It is a beginner question about how to apply css through jQuery :-)

Comment: You're right, +1 for the jQuery solution. Even if this would be a complete foolish workaround if CSS is available ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery rather than the preferred css solution others have posted, try something like:

```
$('#myImage').hover(function() { 
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer'); 
}, function() { 
    $(this).css('cursor','auto'); 
});
```

Comment: This is an overdone approach. It doesn't matter to anyone what the `cursor` property is when the mouse ISN'T hovered over the element. Just do what's in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15684328/901048) for the same result.